# Django Model Field Default to Null

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to have my Django application allow me to have a default value of NULL set for a certain model field. I've looked over the *null*, *blank*, and *default* parameters, but it's not very clear what combination of the three I need to use to get the desired effect. I've tried setting `default=NULL` but it threw an error. If I specify `blank=True, null=True` and no default, will it just default back to NULL come runtime?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Try `default=None`. There is no `NULL` in **python**.

Comment: Just for clarity, the NULL he is referring to is for the Django model field. This allows/disallows a None value to be used for that value, which is stored as a NULL in the database, not in Python. Blank refers to whether or not the value is required for validation in forms/admin/etc.

Comment: @Nexion, `default=None` does not allow or disallow a None value to be used.  It simply tells Django what should be the value of the field if it is not specified.  `null=True` does allow None to be used in the Python code.  It is treated as NULL in the database.  And you're right about blank being used for form validation.

Comment: Just a clarification: I have fresh proof that even if you use default=None, you still need to make null=True or you will not only get a psycopg2 error, you will also get a django.db.utils.IntegrityError as an extra bonus. And if you put all those Nones in there because django told you to make a default value, now you get to undo all of that because, hey, you have all the time in the world, right?

Answer (score 40):

If you specify null=True on the model field then the value will be stored as NULL in the database if the user does not provide a value.

Comment: That isn't true in most of the cases, because usually it will store an empty string.

Comment: @AlfonsIngomar Incorrect, from the docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#null

"If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database. Default is False."

Comment: Look at the next paragraph: Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField **because empty string values will always be stored as empty strings, not as NULL**. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.

Comment: Yes, I have read the docs thanks, no where in the original post or in my reply are string-based fields mentioned.

If you put null=True on a string based field it will be stored as NULL in the database if no data is entered.  I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to point out here that is relevant to this discussion.

It is true in EVERY CASE that if you put null=True empty values will be stored as NULL.  The docs are advising you NOT to put null=True on strings because then they will be stored as NULL, it is not saying that putting null=True will be ignored by string fields.

Comment: Maybe I am interpreting it the wrong way, but what do the docs mean in that case with "because empty string values will always be stored as empty strings, not as NULL"?

Comment: CharFields and TextFields in Django are never saved as NULL. Blank values are stored in the DB as an empty string ('').

Answer (score 28):

- `blank=True`
  allows you to input nothing (i.e `""`, `None`) and keep it empty.
- `null=True`
  means the database row is allowed to be `NULL`.
- `default=None`
  sets the field to `None` if no other value is given.